# Weird boolean artifact

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm having trouble with the boolean modifier. theres this weird artifact that shows after I have picked the object to cut out the other mesh.
[image]

the highlighted is the object that will cut out that plane box underneath.
if I hide that, it shows this.
[image]

here are my setting for the boolean modifier
[image]

I don't understand why this is showing. I even tried to edit the cylinder to make sure  that it doesn't have overlapping faces. But when I do, the boolean doesn't even work.
please help :'>

heres a close up at the weird artifact.
[image]

Comment: How about shade Flat?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you shoud recalculate normals (SHIFT+N).

Also you may need to enable Auto Smooth (in Object Data Properties > Normals) and adjust the angle to improve shading.

[image]